# How to map np.linalg.solve to an array of matrice and keep speed?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a linear problem to solve a number of time: Ax = B
with A, a square matrix of dim n and B, a vector of dimension n. I need to find x:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(2,2)
B = np.random.rand(2)
x = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
```

This was very basic. The problem is that I want to solve this problem many times. The current implementation is like this:

```
import numpy as np
k = 50 # the number of systems to solve
A_list = np.random.rand(k,2,2)
B_list = np.random.rand(k,2)
x = np.array([np.linalg.solve(A,B) for A, B in zip(A_list, B_list)])
```

but it is quite slow. With the help of people of this site, I could remove a huge bottleneck in my code using `np.newaxis` to do smart broadcasting. I wanted to know if there were similar tricks to be used with this kind of functions (`np.linalg.solve`, `np.linalg.det`, etc.).

My tests with `np.vectorize` were a failure.

**Edit:**

### outputs

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> k = 50 # the number of systems to solve
>>> A_list = np.random.rand(k,2,2)
>>> B_list = np.random.rand(k,2)
>>> x = np.array([np.linalg.solve(A,B) for A, B in zip(A_list, B_list)])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-fecc7a7edaf9> in <module>()
----> 1 solution = np.linalg.solve(A_list,B_list)

/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in solve(a, b)
    309     if one_eq:
    310         b = b[:, newaxis]
--> 311     _assertRank2(a, b)
    312     _assertSquareness(a)
    313     n_eq = a.shape[0]

/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _assertRank2(*arrays)
    153         if len(a.shape) != 2:
    154             raise LinAlgError('%d-dimensional array given. Array must be '
--> 155                     'two-dimensional' % len(a.shape))
    156 
    157 def _assertSquareness(*arrays):

LinAlgError: 3-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional
```

Comment: yes, checked with 1.7, it is indeed a new algorithm implementation for [1.8](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#support-for-linear-algebra-on-stacked-arrays)

Comment: Ah ok, then no solution except upgrading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Numpy 1.8

You don't have to do a thing starting from numpy version [`1.8`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#support-for-linear-algebra-on-stacked-arrays):

```
np.linalg.solve(A_list, B_list)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(11)
>>> k = 10
>>> A_list = np.random.rand(k,2,2)
>>> B_list = np.random.rand(k,2)
>>> solution = np.linalg.solve(A_list,B_list)
>>> all(np.allclose(np.dot(A_list[i, :], solution[i,:]), B_list[i, :])
...         for i in range(A_list.shape[0]))
True
```

### Numpy 1.7 and earlier

On older versions one can try to use `scipy.linalg.block_diag`, but it will introduce some overhead, both memory and speed, and for bigger k it will lose to `zip` approach:

```
import scipy.linalg
A = scipy.linalg.block_diag(*A_list)
B = B_list.reshape(-1)
solution = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
solution.reshape(-1,2)
```

### Speed tests for 1.8

For `k=2000; seed=11`:

```
>>> timeit('from __main__ import np, A_list, B_list; np.linalg.solve(A_list, B_list)', number = 100)
0.2786309433182055

>>> timeit('from __main__ import np, A_list, B_list; np.array([np.linalg.solve(A,B) for A, B in zip(A_list, B_list)])', number = 100)
8.431871369126554

>>> timeit('from __main__ import np, A, B; np.linalg.solve(A,B)', number = 100)
43.4851636171674712
```

Comment: Oh, I see... Maybe the numpy version then... 1.7.1. There are explicit assertions there.

Comment: Could you please add the result of a `%timeit` on your solution and mine? Just to figure out the order of magnitude of the speed difference. If you can, I'd like you to do the same thing for k=2000 or something like that. And that would be it.

Comment: @Gael look for speed tests

Comment: Perfect! This is great to have an idea of the relative speed of these. Thanks again.